# Взять значение из textarea

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Пишу чат на node.js, для ввода сообщений использую `textarea`, но у меня не получается взять текст из `textarea`. Получаю ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` при попытке считывания значения из `textarea`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function keypress(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        var inpt = document.getElementById('chat-input');
        var msg = inpt.value;
        inpt.value = "";
        socket.json.send({'event':'message', 'message':msg});
        }
    }



<textarea class="chat-input" name="chat-input" cols="40" rows="5" onkeypress='keypress(event)'></textarea>
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ошибку, не указал id у textarea